# Firestore - how do I remove user's ID from all the documents he's created himself when deleting his account?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

My app deals with users creating simple bookings for themselves so they could keep track of them and so when a booking is created in Firestore, it has an array of users that made the same booking (meaning, same name, day and showtime). How would I go about removing the user's ID from all the arrays in which its mention and leaving the other user IDs in them when deleting his account?

This is the code I have:

```
const ProfileScreen = () => {

  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const auth = getAuth();
  const uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
  const docRef = doc(db, 'users', uid);

  const handleSignOut = () => {
    auth
    .signOut()
    .then(() => {
        navigation.navigate('Welcome')
    })
        .catch(error => alert(error.message))
  }

  const handleDeleteProfile =() => {    
    const korisnikID = getAuth().currentUser.uid;
    const user = getAuth().currentUser;

    auth.signOut()
    .then(() => {
      navigation.navigate('Welcome');
      // removing the user ID from the arrays
      deleteDoc(doc(db, "users", korisnikID))
      .then(() => {        
        deleteUser(user);
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    });  
  }

  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUser = async () => {
      const snap = await getDoc(docRef)
      setUser({user, ...snap.data()})
    }
    getUser()
  },[])

  return (
<View style = {styles.container}>   
  <View style = {styles.profileContainer}>
  <Image source={require('../assets/profile.jpeg')} style = {styles.image} />
  <View style = {styles.profileInfo}>
  <Text style = {styles.name}>{user.name} ({user.age})</Text>
  <Text style = {styles.location}>{user.city}, {user.country}</Text>
  </View>
  </View>

  <View style = {styles.infoContainer}>
  <Text style = {styles.text1}>Username</Text>
    <View style = {styles.info}>
      <Text style = {styles.text2}>{user.username}</Text>
    </View>
    <Text style = {styles.text1}>Favorite movie:</Text>
    <View style = {styles.info}>
      <Text style = {styles.text2}>{user.movie}</Text>
    </View>
    <Text style = {styles.text1}>About me</Text>
    <View style = {styles.info}>
      <Text style = {styles.text2}>{user.bio}</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
  <View style = {styles.buttonContainer}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress = {handleSignOut}
    style = {styles.button}>
      <Text style = {styles.buttonText}>Sign out</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
  <View style = {styles.buttonContainer}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress = {handleDeleteProfile}
    style = {styles.buttonDelete}>
      <Text style = {styles.buttonText}>Delete account</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
</View>
 )
}

export default ProfileScreen
```

This is what the Firestore database looks like:

[image: User fields]

[image: Booking fields]

Comment: Did Prakhar Sharma's answer help?

Comment: I'm kind of confused how to put it in a loop and where to put the loop exactly. Could you help me out?

Comment: So you need code or an idea to solve the issue?

Comment: I have Prakhar's code and I get how it works but I'm not sure where to put it exactly (in a loop and where to place said loop).

Comment: So did Prakhar Sharma's solve you problem?

Comment: It did not, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code in the loop to remove the specific id
This code without a loop will remove the first occurrence of the user id.
{put the user id you want to remove} should be replaced by [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vv69X.png) the id mentioned here.

The following code is for users db

```
var postsRef = db.collection('users');
var query = postsRef.where('id', '==', '{put the user id you want to remove}').get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
        var deleteDoc = db.collection('users').doc(doc.id).delete();
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });
```

The following code is for booking db

```
var postsRef = db.collection('booking');
var query = postsRef.where('id', '==', '{put the user id you want to remove}').get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
        var deleteDoc = db.collection('booking').doc(doc.id).delete();
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });
```

The following code is for movies db

```
var postsRef = db.collection('movies');
var query = postsRef.where('id', '==', '{put the user id you want to remove}').get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
        var deleteDoc = db.collection('movies').doc(doc.id).delete();
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do I put this code inside handleDeleteProfile?

Comment: I'm not sure how to put it in a loop and where, I'm sorry.